# Adding strings in lines (regex notepad plusplus)

Tags: regex, notepad++

I've seen people asking stuff related to regex and i thought id ask my quesstion. I have a file with many lines like this:

374327711199385

and I need to make it to this per each line:
3743-277111-99385

It's a big file so can't do it manually. Any ideas on how to make it automatic with regex? Thanks so much!

Comment: Is the number grouping the same for all your lines?

Comment: i have numbers like this per each line: 374327711199385 all same length

Comment: You could use column mode to insert the `-` at the same location in each line. See https://notepad-plus-plus.org/features/column-mode-editing.html

Answer (score 0):

To perform this, you need to search with this expression:

```
^(\d{4})(\d{6})(\d{5})$
```

And replace with this:

```
$1-$2-$3
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! ! And thanks Lars, havent thought of that :)

Comment: @Jenny No need to thank. :) By the way, welcome to StackOverflow! If my answer solved your problem, you can [accept and vote up for it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251399/6403828).